# How can I test/mock external code or external dependencies using moq?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm using Moq for mocking of my code in unit testing. It's ok to mock the code without external dependencies. Below code is my last dependencies which I mocked

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Executes the request.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="booking">The booking.</param>
protected override void ExecuteRequest(BookingModel.Booking booking)
{
    var request = this.CreateRequest(this.TravelContext, booking);
    using (var proxy = this.TravelContext.CreateProxy<IMonitorBookingServiceProxy>())
    {
        var response = proxy.AutoCancelBooking(request);
        this.AddResponseInfos(response.ResponseInfos);
    }
}
```

I mock the above code like this

```cs
// mock the IMonitorBookingServiceProxy
Mock<IMonitorBookingServiceProxy> mockedMonitorBookingContext = new Mock<IMonitorBookingServiceProxy>() { DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock };
mockedMonitorBookingContext.Setup(x => x.AutoCancelBooking(It.IsAny<AutoCancelBookingRequest>())).Returns(autoCancelBookingResponse).Verifiable();
ProxyFactory.Configure<IMonitorBookingServiceProxy>(mockedMonitorBookingContext.Object);
```

it's return the response to me correctly.
but my problem is that there's a lot of scenarios and classes to be test inside `proxy.AutoCancelBooking(request);` function.

How How i can test or mocked that that classes and dependencies .

Comment: To test `AutoCancelBooking` you have not to mock the `IMonitorBookingServiceProxy` but to create class that implements the interface and provide external dependencies for it (by mocking those dependencies instances). Then you can create test cases to check the `AutoCancelBooking` logic implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Purpose of mocking is to removing the dependencies to test your code, So, in my code

```
/// <summary>
/// Executes the request.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="booking">The booking.</param>
protected override void ExecuteRequest(BookingModel.Booking booking)
{
    var request = this.CreateRequest(this.TravelContext, booking);
    using (var proxy = this.TravelContext.CreateProxy<IMonitorBookingServiceProxy>())
    {
        var response = proxy.AutoCancelBooking(request);
        this.AddResponseInfos(response.ResponseInfos);
    }
}
```

when I'm calling `proxy.AutoCancelBooking(request);` it calls the Web API which is dependencies which can't be mocked, Tht's why we will generate mocked response and return it from above function. I'm already doing it right.

Answer (score 1):

You say that are a lot of scenarios to be tested **inside** the `IMonitorBookingServiceProxy.AutoCancelBooking` request function. Do you want to test the functionality within `IMonitorBookingServiceProxy.AutoCancelBooking` or do you want to test the functionality of `ExecuteRequest` depending on different responses returned by `IMonitorBookingServiceProxy.AutoCancelBooking`?

Comment: I want to test the functionality of MonitorBookingServiceProxy.AutoCancelBooking

Comment: In that case you should do as mentioned by @oleksa. If you want to test `IMonitorBookingServiceProxy.AutoCancelBooking` you will probably also have a class that implements this interface. That class will have dependencies injected in its constructor. You have to mock those dependencies and setup their behavior to test the execution paths in the class that implements `IMonitorBookingServiceProxy.AutoCancelBooking`.